# How to Prevent Project.params from Syncing when Saving

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio SSDT, I have set up multiple Project Configurations, DEV, QA, PROD. Also, I have parameters set up for each configuration, so I can easily deploy to each environment with different parameters. However, when i edit a parameter's value and save, the new value is saved to the parameter for each configuration.

Here are the steps I followed: 
First I edit the value in aNewTestParameter
[image]

Then, I save the Project.params file and switch to the QA Configuration. Notice it also has the DEV Value. 
[image]

How do I prevent this save from overwriting the values in my other configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the parameter to configurations (third button above the Name field in the screen-shots).  Next, set these values accordingly in the "Manage Parameter Values" window that will follow.  Upon doing this, the parameter values will correspond to whichever configuration is chosen in the configuration drop-down.